# Getting ExecJS::ProgramError following GettingStarted guide while trying to change the basic application homepage

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to make sure you pay attention that the **error is not** in the javascript line, it's in marked at the line containing the stylesheet link tag!

I was following this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I get to part 4.3 Setting the Application Home Page
I've done everything up to this point, used the generate command to make a new controller and a view named "Welcome".

I've changed the app/views/welcome/index.html.erb content to a simple <h1>Hi</h1>, and then added a line in config/routes.rb which made it look like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
```

After saving those modifications, going to localhost:3000 gives me the following error:

[image]

I am using rails 5.0.1 and ruby 2.3.3 in case anyone asks

UPDATE:

I found a thread on some forum in German that seems to be dealing with the same problem. The person there suggested to modify the gemfile and add:
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

as well as run this command:
bundle update coffee-script-source

I've tried this but to no avail, it cannot execute the command(system cannot find the path specified).

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a solution after a lot of failed attempts and frustration.

Apparently, the default runtime doesn't work properly with ruby on rails in windows. What fixes the error is installing the node.js runtime.

Download and install the node.js javascript runtime and don't forget to turn off your server and run it again before visiting the site again.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try to uncomment ruby-racer gem in Gemfile and run bundle.